# Make camera follow and rotate with player without childing it

Tags: unity, camera, rotation

I want to have a camera, that follow the player, without childing it to the player object. So far I have this one line, that follows the player, but does not rotate with it (meaning the camera should look where the player's front is looking, how can I do it?

```
transform.position = player.transform.position + offset;
```

Comment: Why don't you want to parent the camera to the player?

Comment: because if the player dies (gets destroyed) the camera will go with it. I want to make it like some game, where you die, and the camera stays at your corpse for a while, before respawning and the camera gets back to you

Comment: Just don't destroy the player, play an animation or disable the mesh renderer or collider.

Comment: In your die script , you can "deatach"  camera from player object

Comment: yes, but I need to know how can I make it this way

Comment: To detach an object from it's parent just use transform.parent = null;

Comment: I meant I need to know how can I make it the way I asked in my OP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
transform.position = player.transform.position - player.transform.forward * distance;
transform.LookAt(player.transform);
```

where float distance is the distance of camera form player

Consider also the solution 2 : Make camera child of player and in your player die script , you can "deatach" camera from player object

```
transform.parent = null;
```

Comment: the code doesn't work, because the camera slowly goes to the player, and then goes inside of him, then out, and its all very weird...

Comment: still the same, also you can't use multiplications in Vector3

Comment: edited , ofset changed in float distance

Answer (score 0):

You can multiply vector3 by using vector3.cross(vector a, vector b);

And here, its not multiplying to vector3. Its multiplying to just z axis. Transform.forward is z axis.