# How can I make the camera that follows my character position also follow the character rotation?

Tags: unity, c#, camera

So I've tried to make the camera also follow my character rotation, I tried using the same process that I did for the position follow, using quaternion and transform.rotation but it was giving me some errors. Since I'm pretty new, I will ask for the best solution for my problem, here's the code:

```
void Start()
{
    followPos = transform.position - player.transform.position;
}


void LateUpdate()
{
    transform.position = player.transform.position + followPos;
}
```

Comment: Please note that all of your questions have been retagged. Unless you're developing a scripting language for games, or you're integrating one to your game, the tag [tag:scripting] should not be applied; also the UnityScript language is no longer supported by Unity, so you should use the tag [tag:c#] instead of the tag [tag:unityscript]. Please tag responsibility (and read the description of the tag before using them :p).

Comment: So sorry Alexandre, thanks for the information and also for the text correction since my main is not English. ;_;

Comment: It looks like this [has been asked before](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/104838/make-camera-follow-and-rotate-with-player-without-childing-it).

Comment: it works perfectly just gotta fix the angle, thank you once again Alexandre